# Matlab Interface Issue - seg fault?

Tags: worhp

for my problem Matlab crashes in the 5th loop of the main loop in worhp.cpp in the subroutine

```
 if (GetUserAction(&cnt, callWorhp))
        {
            Worhp(&opt, &wsp, &par, &cnt);
            // No DoneUserAction!
        }
```

with a seg fault.  It would be great if you could help me to debug by providing information on the opt, wsp, par and cnt structs and what to look for.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Have you tried running with CheckStructureDF/DG/HM set to true? These can help finding some simple issues with user matrix structures, should this be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently having trouble with a similar issue. In one case, I was able to find an error by checking, whether the solver was able to terminate without an error when using approximated hessian matrices, instead of providing them myself. The error in this case occured, because I gave the library the wrong number of nonzero hessian entries and accessed entries of the hessian matrix that weren't allocated by the solver in my hessian function. Maybe your error is caused by a similar problem.

Kind regards,
Jan

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for your reply. In my case I use the exact same sparse matrices with a different solver which is why I am rather sure that the sparsity pattern is correct.